# Mass Breakdown of Apollo CSM by Subsystems? (also Cost Breakdown)

Tags: apollo-program, design, cost, life-support, mass

I am looking for a mass breakdown of the Apollo Command and Service Module by subsystems, like this Lunar Module's chart from the NASA publication [After LM](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20190031985/downloads/20190031985_rev1.pdf#page=18). I am particularly interested in how much of the spacecraft's total mass was occupied by the ECLSS.

---

I also want to find the cost breakdown of Apollo hardware development and how much was necessary to develop the life support components, if such analysis exists. There is a brief breakdown of budget allocation in [Apollo by the Numbers](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029.pdf#page=291), but this was all I could find.